# Pandas sort each row and print the top 5

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to sort 25 columns individually and then print out the top 5 rows from each column. I assume that I will need to use a loop for this, but can't seem to figure it out.

I currently have:

`df.sort_values(by=['A'], ascending=False)
 df.head()`

`df.sort_values(by=['B'], ascending=False)
 df.head()`

`df.sort_values(by=['C'], ascending=False)
 df.head() ...`

The goal is to repeat this over many columns without having 25 lines of code.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem, ... if so, do you really want to miss out on honing your own programming skills.  Most learn through failure (i.e. fail often enough to succeed).  A barrier to completing any assignment is being paralyzed by perfection.  Do it badly first, then improve upon it.  Write it in 50 lines, verify correctness, then work to condense the code while maintaining correctness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you rather want to print out each column separately, this should work

```
df.apply(lambda x: print(x.sort_values(ascending=False).head(5)), axis=0)
```

Comment: I do think he wants to first sort the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=0), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
print(df.iloc[:5])
```

Comment: When I use this method the values are inverted. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question... This ended up working. Perhaps there is a more concise way to do it.

```
index = df.iloc[:,0]
for i in range(1,25):
        a = exp.iloc[:,(i)]
        b = a.sort_values(ascending=False)
        c = pd.DataFrame(data=b)
        print(c.head().join(index))
```

Comment: This is honestly a pretty poor solution, since looping is not only constrained to the size of your given example, but it also is far slower than the other given answers

Comment: Still learning. Thanks for the feedback.